# Is it safe to travel to Israel in early 2024?

Tags: safety, israel, event-based-effects

I am from India. I got MSc research from one university in Israel. Currently I am in the process of applying for a visa, as I might relocate to Israel by January 15. I would be staying in the university's dormitory.

Is Israel currently safe to travel to, due to the war?

Comment: I would say that wars are unpredictable and that others can not know how much risk is acceptable for you.

Comment: @Willeke If I stay in university's dormitory only, then also I will not safe?

Comment: I do not have a cristal ball to predict how the war will evolve.

Comment: This: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_intentional_homicide_rate ... says it is actually safer in Israel than in India, even if one includes the Israel-side victims of the ongoing war.

Comment: India and Israel both have same problem terrorism, although I experienced with that in India but I don't know how is it in Israel.

Comment: Given that there are rockets being fired which occasionally hit civilian targets, a dormitory probably isn’t any more safe than anywhere else.

Comment: In addition to all the other wise things said, it also depends on where in Israel you are going. If the dormitory is e.g. very close to the Lebanese border there is probably a higher chance of it getting hit by a rocket fired from Lebanon.

Comment: FCDO in the UK says [no](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/israel).

Comment: Your best bet is to check travel insurance and advice from your government (note that there will be variations between nationality although the UK and US governments generally provide good advice). If you're going to study, you will probably need some form of insurance, so if it's not available, stay home.

Comment: @StuartF  I already did travel, health insurance both.

Comment: I would say now is a great time to go to Israel as hotels should be cheaper than usual and tourist sites will be less busy. Only problem is that plane tickets are now more expensive.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am expecting your answer, so please open the question and please answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of fatal traffic accidents per inhabit is significantly higher in India than in Israel (16.6 per 100k in India vs 4.2 per 100k in Israel). Scaled to the population of Israel, that means that about 1200 people are saved every year because Israeli traffic is safer than Indian traffic.

With the tragic exception of the October 7th 2023 attacks, terrorism has never claimed nearly as many lives in Israel as this difference.

Of course none of us can realiably predict the future, where in India vs where in Israel will matter, etc, but overall I would conclude that **Israel is significantly safer than India**.

Sources:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_traffic-related_death_rate
https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/number-of-terrorism-fatalities-in-israel

Comment: *"With the tragic exception of the October 7th 2023 attacks"* - The terrorist attack is entirely the point. The risk of terrorist attacks in Israel right now is extremely elevated since it is in a state of active war. You can't just say "but traffic deaths are worse during normal times" since it is not currently normal times. If someone asked whether it was safe to travel to Ukraine would you start quoting traffic statistics?

Comment: @DavidK You can rephrase the argument. Including the terrorist attack in 2023 Israel was about as safe as India is in any given year. In every other year before 2023 Israel was much safer than India.

Comment: @DavidK Way more Ukranians are dying in traffic accidents than by missile/drone attacks away from the frontlines (about 20 per day). So yes, if someone is asking whether travelling to Kyiv or Lviv is currently safe, they should be worried about traffic, not the war.

Comment: The great thing about averages is that they can be used to prove almost anything!

Comment: @Arno I guess I should have phrased the Ukraine argument better - if someone asked whether it was safe to travel within 100 km of the front lines in Ukraine (since almost all of Israel is), would traffic statistics be relevant? You know, according to the link you provide, Afghanistan has fewer traffic fatalities than India so it must be safer too!

Comment: @DavidK Unlike the case for Israel, in Afghanistan it makes sense to assume significant risks for foreigners that don't pertain to locals, and I wouldn't trust their data on traffic accidents. But overall, checking traffic accident data is a great way to avoid giving undue weight to particularly newsworthy risks.

Comment: Not a good answer. Averages taken in periods in which rare events are uncommon are not good summaries of periods in which rare events are likely to be increased in frequency. I'm sure that traffic accidents were a major cause of death in Hiroshima on August 5, 1945, too.

Comment: @Obie 2.0 The data in my second link includes the various intifadas, eg the year 2002 with 457 deaths due to terrorism.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not. When a war is being fought in a country—and while the war is primarily within the Gaza Strip, not Israel itself, given the size of Israel, that is not much of a distinction—it is impossible to accurately say that any area is safe. Hamas could launch attacks that hit targets within Israel, their soldiers could cross the border  and commit attacks there, or other countries could take the opportunity to join the war and attack Israel more directly—something that is perhaps more probable in this conflict than in, say, northern Nigeria. Even misfires or ammunition depot incidents from the Israel side cannot be ruled out.

Will you probably be fine, if the war continues as it foreseeably will? Yes. But the problem is things that cannot be easily foreseen. Remember that the current Israeli invasion of the Gaza Strip occurred precisely in response to attacks within Israel that many believed to be impossible.

Comment: This is a good general statement but Israel is special in the sense that not a single major tourist site has seen *any* combat activity since 1967. Tel Aviv has not seen any combat since 1948. There's been a few terrorist attacks here and there but they've claimed far less lives than traffic accidents. The rockets likewise were never a threat to any tourist sites.